# Dictionary unpacking in Python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

In Python 3 when I had to merge two dicts I usually did something like this -

```
payload = {'key':'value'} 
another_payload = {'another_key':'another_val'}
final_payload = {**payload, **another_payload}
```

However, now when I do the same in Python 2.7 it throws a Syntax Error. Does Python2 not support it? If it supports how to do the above?

Comment: This `payload.update(another_payload)`?

Comment: `update()` method updates the dict in place. I had two dicts and needed to dump both of them to another in a more pythonic way. Seems I have to stick to update

Answer (score 0):

This works, if it suits you:

```
dicts = [payload, another_payload]
final_payload = {k: v for d in dicts for k, v in d.items()}
```